# how to write a conditional constraint in CPLEX python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cplex, docplex

I have a model that has one binary variable x [i] [j] [k]. I need to add a constraint that fullfils this condition:

```
if x[i][j][k1]==1  and  x[j][i][k2]==1 

Then:

 k2-k1>8
```

I have this code but I assum it is not correct :

```
  mdl.add((y[(i,j,k)]+y[(j,i,k1)]==2),(k1-k>8) )
```

I also, put this:

```
 mdl.add(mdl.if_then(y[(i,j,k1)]+y[(j,i,k2)]==2, k2-k1>8))
```

but I got this error:

```
    raise DOcplexException(resolved_message)

DOcplexException: Expecting linear constraint, got: False
```

How can I model this with cplex python API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

let me share the if then example from

https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/making-optimization-simple-python-alex-fleischer/

```
from docplex.mp.model import Model

mdl = Model(name='buses')
nbbus40 = mdl.integer_var(name='nbBus40')
nbbus30 = mdl.integer_var(name='nbBus30')
mdl.add_constraint(nbbus40*40 + nbbus30*30 >= 300, 'kids')
mdl.minimize(nbbus40*500 + nbbus30*400)

mdl.solve()

for v in mdl.iter_integer_vars():
   print(v," = ",v.solution_value)

print()
print("with if nb buses 40 more than 3  then nbBuses30 more than 7")

#if then constraint
mdl.add(mdl.if_then(nbbus40>=3,nbbus30>=7))
mdl.minimize(nbbus40*500 + nbbus30*400)

mdl.solve()



for v in mdl.iter_integer_vars():
    print(v," = ",v.solution_value)
```

and if you want to see and in the if

```
from docplex.mp.model import Model

mdl = Model(name='buses')
nbbus40 = mdl.integer_var(name='nbBus40')
nbbus30 = mdl.integer_var(name='nbBus30')
mdl.add_constraint(nbbus40*40 + nbbus30*30 >= 300, 'kids')
mdl.minimize(nbbus40*500 + nbbus30*400)

mdl.solve()

for v in mdl.iter_integer_vars():
   print(v," = ",v.solution_value)

print()
print("with if nb buses 40 more than 3 and less than 7 then nbBuses30 more than 7")

#if then constraint
mdl.add(mdl.if_then((nbbus40>=3) + (nbbus40<=7)>=2,nbbus30>=7))
mdl.minimize(nbbus40*500 + nbbus30*400)

mdl.solve()



for v in mdl.iter_integer_vars():
    print(v," = ",v.solution_value)
```

which you can also rewrite

```
from docplex.mp.model import Model

mdl = Model(name='buses')
nbbus40 = mdl.integer_var(name='nbBus40')
nbbus30 = mdl.integer_var(name='nbBus30')
mdl.add_constraint(nbbus40*40 + nbbus30*30 >= 300, 'kids')
mdl.minimize(nbbus40*500 + nbbus30*400)

mdl.solve()

for v in mdl.iter_integer_vars():
   print(v," = ",v.solution_value)

print()
print("with if nb buses 40 more than 3 and less than 7 then nbBuses30 more than 7")

#if then constraint
mdl.add((((nbbus40>=3) + (nbbus40<=7)>=2))<=(nbbus30>=7))
mdl.minimize(nbbus40*500 + nbbus30*400)

mdl.solve()



for v in mdl.iter_integer_vars():
    print(v," = ",v.solution_value)
```

Comment: I tried if_then like this:  mdl.add(mdl.if_then((y[(i,j,k1)])+(y[(j,i,k2)])==2, k2-k1>8)) but I got an error: raise DOcplexException(resolved_message)

DOcplexException: Expecting linear constraint, got: False

Comment: if I use mdl.add(mdl.if_then((nbbus40>=3) + (nbbus40<=7)>=2,5>=7)) then I get the same error. In the then you should have a constraint instead of a value. What you can do is move to something like mdl.add(((nbbus40>=3) + (nbbus40<=7)>=2)<=(5>=7))

Comment: Something like  mdl.add(((y[i][j][k1])+(y[i][j][k2])==2)<=(k2-k1>8)) throws keyError:0

Comment: And if you write k2-k1>=9 instead of k2-k1>8 ?

Comment: I got : DOcplexException: Expecting sequence of linear constraints, got: docplex.mp.constr.IfThenConstraint[](_{y_0_1_12 == 1},y_1_0_19 == 0,true=1) at position 0. It somehow makes sence because y1_0_19 should not necessearily be= 1. any of the y1_0_k2 can be equal to 1

Answer (score 0):

`Model.if_then` links two linear constraints left-to-right. If the first one becomes satisfied, the second will be satisfied too.

In your case , I understand that in `k2-k1>8` there are no decision variables involved. SO this is purely data-dependent, known at model build time.

In that case, the causality works the other way round: if k2-k1>8 then both x[i,j,k1] and x[i,j,k2] must be equal to 1.

The simplest code is then:

```
if k2-k1>8:
   m.add(x[i,j,k1] == 1)
   m.add(x[i,j,k2] == 1)
```

Comment: This is not my only constraint, I have other constraints that may make some of the variables equal to 0. This has a conflict with your suggested code. I get: KeyError: 0

Comment: Ok, so I got misled by your original post. If you create your variables as dictionaries with triplets as keys, then the correct code is: x[i,j,k1] ==1...(see edited post)

Comment: However, my basic point remains: if a condition that depends uniquely on data determines that a variable must be equal to 1, this part of the model is frozen so Model.if_then is not appropriate.

Comment: This causes my model to get no solution

Comment: You can find here: https://github.com/IBMDecisionOptimization/docplex-examples/blob/master/examples/mp/jupyter/infeasible.ipynb a notebook describing all tools in Docplex to investigate infeasible models.